# How to remove the global mutable variable in the code?

Tags: f#

The following code finds the `maxLen` giving a list of value. The `maxLen` is a mutable value. How to remove it for more functional practice?

```
let reject pos = // reject a given pos, the implementation is contrived
    let s = [4; 9; 14] // Just an example, any value may be rejected 
    s |> List.exists (fun x -> x = pos)

let getLength pos = if pos % 3 = 0 then pos * 2 else pos 

let mutable maxLen = 0

let getNewPosAndSetMaxLength pos len = // For each new position, check if the result of `getLenth pos` is larger than previous ones.
    let direction = if len < 1 then -1 else 1
    let newPos = 
        match [1..abs(len)] |> List.tryFind (fun i -> reject (pos + i * direction)) with
        | Some p -> p
        | None -> pos + len
    let newLen = getLength newPos
    maxLen <- if newLen > maxLen then newLen else maxLen
    newPos

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let pos = 0
    [3; -2; 6; 7] 
    |> List.iter (fun x -> 
        let pos = getNewPosAndSetMaxLength pos x
        ()
    )
    printfn "%d" maxLen
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

Comment: Have you tried using ``List.fold`` instead of ``List.iter`` and the mutable?

Comment: Thanks, I think I will need to change the function `getNewPosAndSetMaxLength` to return both newPos and length then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you change `getNewPostAndSetMaxLength` to take the current max length and return a pair of `(pos, maxLength)` you can use `List.fold`:

```
let getNewPosAndSetMaxLength maxLen pos len = // For each new position, check if the result of `getLenth pos` is larger than previous ones.
    let direction = if len < 1 then -1 else 1
    let newPos = 
        match [1..abs(len)] |> List.tryFind (fun i -> reject (pos + i * direction)) with
        | Some p -> p
        | None -> pos + len
    let newLen = getLength newPos
    let maxLen' = if newLen > maxLen then newLen else maxLen
    (newPos, maxLen')

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let (lastPos, maxLen) = [3; -2; 6; 7] |> List.fold (fun (pos, maxLen) x -> 
        getNewPosAndSetMaxLength maxLen pos x) (0, 0)
    printfn "%d" maxLen
    0 // return an integer exit code
```